# What's a good way to convert my LINQ-to-SQL objects into my model objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I've been noticing when I pull things out of the my MSSQL db using LINQ-to-SQL using something simple like:

```
    public IEnumerable<Contact> GetAll()
    {
        var Contacts = from c in _context.Contacts
                      select new Models.Contact
                      {
                          ContactID = c.ContactID,
                          FirstName = c.FirstName,
                          LastName = c.LastName,
                          Email = c.Email,
                          Phone = c.Phone,
                          Address1 = c.Address1,
                          Address2 = c.Address2,
                          City = c.City,
                          State = c.State,
                          Zip = c.Zip,
                          HighImportance = (bool)c.HighImportance,
                          PrimaryContact = (bool)c.PrimaryContact,
                          OfficeLocation = c.OfficeLocation
                      };
        return Contacts;
    }
```

I have a complex object (foreign key reference) to an OfficeLocations table which I would like to populate.  If I do something like:

```
_context.OfficeLocations.SingleOrDefault(ol => ol.OfficeLocationID == c.OfficeLocationID);
```

Then this returns the type which is generated by my DBML.  Up to now I've been using something like:

```
OfficeLocation = new OfficeLocation
            {
                OfficeLocationID = c.OfficeLocationID,
                Name = c.OfficeLocation.Name,
                Phone = c.OfficeLocation.Phone
            }
```

But I feel like there should be a much better way to do it, maybe by using extension methods on my DBML data objects or something?

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should checkout [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/). It's a very good library that would help you setup mapping between objects in your application. For example, you might have domain entities and a layer of DTO's; then you can use AutoMapper to map from your entities to the corresponding DTO's, which I assume is what you're looking to do.

Comment: Dumb question: What is a DTO?

Comment: DTO stands for "Data Transfer Object". Which is an object used to carry data between different layers of your application. It is mostly used to pass data from the business layer to the service layer and then across the wire. Why? Because your business layer might be too complex and probably has circular dependencies, which will most likely not be serialized when being sent over the wire.

Comment: Looks like it's called DTO Flattening, thanks Kassem, totally forgot about AutoMapper :)!